# Stop the authorization header from logging

Tags: web-api-testing, rest

I have a response log of a Rest Request as shown below:

```
Request method: DELETE
Request URI:    https://Some_URI
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Authorization=Bearer AuthenticationTocken
                Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:           <none>
```

I Want to log the entire response but not the Authorization part from the header, Result should like.

```
    Request method: DELETE
    Request URI:    https://Some_URI
    Proxy:          <none>
    Request params: <none>
    Query params:   <none>
    Form params:    <none>
    Path params:    <none>
    Headers:        Accept=*/*
                    Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Cookies:        <none>
    Multiparts:     <none>
    Body:           <none>
```

Created the Header with the code:

```
Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put( HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,ContentType.JSON);
        headers.put( HttpHeaders.ACCEPT,ContentType.ANY);    
  RequestSpecification requestSpecification = given().log().all()
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, BEARER_KEY + getAuthorizationToken())
                .headers(headers);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are using Rest Assured to test, In that case you cannot remove the header completely but you can hide the details - [blacklist-headers-from-logging](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#blacklist-headers-from-logging)

Usage Sample :

```
given().config(RestAssuredConfig.config().logConfig(LogConfig.logConfig().blacklistHeader("Set-Cookie"))).when()
                .get("URL").then().log().all().statusCode(200);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In rest assured, you can blacklist the headers in all the request using below filter.
This will even blacklist the logs exported to the text file.

```
HashSet<String> blacklistedHeaders=new HashSet();
blacklistedHeaders.add("XSRF_TOKEN");

RequestSpecification
.config(RestAssured.config().logConfig(LogConfig.logConfig().blacklistHeaders(blacklistedHeaders)))
.filter(new RequestLoggingFilter(LogDetail.ALL, true, new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Logging.txt")), false,blacklistedHeaders))
```